# On an iPad, ExtJS dropdowns aren't dismissed when touching outside the dropdown

Tags: ipad, extjs, drop-down-menu

When I have dropdown menus that I have touched to open using the iPad, I cannot get out of the menu by touching elsewhere in the window, as would happen on a PC.

I am running the webapp with Safari, and I understand that Safari does not register clicks on non-clickable regions for the iPad, so I am wondering if this is the reason that I am unable to exit out of the dropdown menus, and, if so, how I can fix this.

I know that ExtJS is not meant for iPad, but I believe that my problem is unrelated to ExtJS's bad support for iPad.

Thanks in advance, Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add an event handler to the main panel. I used the following to achieve this.

```
// "forms" was used for a dual purpose
var forms = Ext.dom.Query.select('{overflow=auto}');
    for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {

        // If the element's ID has "panel" in it
        if (forms[i].id.search("panel") == 0) {
            var panel = document.getElementById(forms[i].id);

            //touchmove works the best of the events I found
            panel.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
                for (var j = 0; j < myComboboxes.length; j++) {
                    myComboboxes[j].collapse();
                }
            }, false);
        }
    }
}
```